# Solvability of Higher Degree Polynomials by Bring Radicals

Tags: galois-theory

A Bring radical of $a$ is any root of the polynomial $x^5+x+a$. It is known that we can solve the quintic if we're allowed to use the Bring radical.

Now, I was wondering what happens if we generalize: define the $n$th Bring radical of $a$ to be some root of $x^n+x+a$. Can all higher degree polynomials by solved by radicals and Bring radicals? if not, is there a criterion on the Galois group that is equivalent to solvability by radicals and generalized Bring radicals?

Comment: Sadly we cannot.  Of course some higher degree polynomials can be solved with the additional availability of generalized Bring radicals, but not all can be.

Comment: See the answers at MathOverflow, [Using higher-order Bring radicals to solve arbitrary polynomials](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/61409/using-higher-order-bring-radicals-to-solve-arbitrary-polynomials)

Comment: I remembered getting into this material before, but had trouble finding it!  It was actually a Computational Science question, [Why can't Householder reflections diagonalize a matrix?](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1864/why-cant-householder-reflections-diagonalize-a-matrix), and the connection is likely unobvious.  However the issue is whether direct methods for solving eigenvalues (polynomials roots) are competitive with iterative methods.  There is a historical connection with [Hilbert's 13th problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_thirteenth_problem).